# is it possible to set a Host as a service name with nginx proxy?

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, keycloak, nginx-reverse-proxy

I have a frontend, backend and a sso (keycloak) application which actually works except one point.

I have 3 subdomains:

```
1- sso.domain.com (keycloak) -> sso-service
2- domain.com (frontend) -> frontend-service
3- api.domain.com (backend) -> backend-service
```

I want to login on frontend and use the same token for backend api. Actually everything is there and its almost working except keycloak sends "active:false, which means the given token does not exist or invalid" because, the token is getting generated on frontend with the frontend.domain.com. And if I want to use the same token to get information from backend, backend sends introspect request an keycloak with the given token to identify, if the given token is still valid or not and finally backend receives the response from keycloak active true or false.

I know the problem is actually the domainname and I am trying to trick keycloak with proxy_set_header but but keycloak still shows the frontend.mydomain.com as requesUri.

Frontend Nginx configuration:

```
location /login {
  proxy_pass http://sso-service/auth;
  proxy_set_header Host frontend-service;
}
```

I hope the question is clear, if not; please ask me so I can provide more information.

Comment: Have you used ingress?

Comment: yes via ingress I am handling domains and services.